# How to implement a team site( document library, search, views dashboards) with No server access, No Sharepoint designer access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, document-library, search, central-administration

I am new to sharepoint, and have started a project and Just finished to gather requirements. I have also read about sharepoint and I have a big picture of  it.

1. This is my development environment and my situation:
         * I am using sharepoint entreprise 2010 
         * No access to the server ----> no central administration access
         * One of the sharepoint server administrator told me the company does not use Sharepoint Designer
         * Admin people have created a team site for me that I am using to implement The project (document management, search , dashboard)
2. According to the requirement gathered:
       I will be creating document libraries with default permission level,metadata implementation, views will be created, they is no workflow to implement,advanced search of documents will be implemented and some dashboards too.
3. My questions are:

   - Is it possible to  do all this with no  SP designer , I mean everything using the SP graphical interface? If no what alternative do I have for Interface design with no Sharepoint designer at All?
   - To achieve search for example , i read that i need some set up in the central administration, But I don't have access to that,  Can I implement a good search feature without doing any set up on server (my site will allow search only in our document libraries, so I want the search to be in the team site)? what option do I have?
   - Is there anyway to implement a dashboard or any KPI( Key performance indicator ) with no SP designer ? what do I need and how to go about it?

   Any suggestion and links are welcome.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are tackling a lot of stuff for your first time out with SharePoint.  The answer is YES you can do this.  "How" you do it depends on the way your administrators deployed SharePoint and what services they made available to you.

First - with Search.  Some things do have to be configured in Central Admin, but not everything.  More than likely for your first iteration you won't have to worry about this.  There are some search setting exposed to your site (Under site settings) for some configuration, but more than likely you will be customizing the web parts and their configurations.  If you post a more search specific question we can help you here in what you have to do.  Review some of the other questions asked here around search web parts:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=SharePoint+Search+2010+webparts

As for KPI's and Dashboards you have a few options:

1. Use the default lists and libraries can customize their views to your needs. There are KPI lists and webparts available to you to use with these as well.
2. Build the dashboard in Excel and expose thru excel viewer web parts.
3. Use PowerPivot to link to lists and display your data from excel services (ability to refresh data from server), but admins must have configured it.
4. Use Reporting Services - this isn't technically SharePoint, but if admins have or will configure it, it is a great tool to use.  Not really geared for Dashboards (hence the report name), but can do the job in simple cases, and you can schedule reports to be re-ran and updated.
5. PerformancePoint - this is a SharePoint service specifically for Dash boarding, it can be complicated to use, and I've never really been a big fan of it (2013 has improvements over 2010 that makes it more palatable), but you should be aware of it.

There are some other options available, especially if you know HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well (at that point your options are almost limitless).

I want to put **Emphasis** on the fact that, PowerPivot PerformancePoint, and Reporting Services all have to be configured before you can use them, so they may not be available to you.

You can do a few searches to help with these:

- Excel: http://www.bing.com/search?q=SharePoint+2010+Excel+webpart&form=U281DF&pc=U281
- KPI: http://www.bing.com/search?q=SharePoint+2010+KPI+easy&form=U281DF&pc=U281
- PowerPivot & SharePoint Lists: http://www.bing.com/search?q=SharePoint+2010+PowerPivot+import+sharepont+lists&form=U281DF&pc=U281
- SharePoint and Reporting Services: http://www.bing.com/search?q=SharePoint+2010+create+reports+service&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=sharepoint+2010+create+reports+service&sc=0-30&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=c5f2b7a7cfe94fd1bbf5eadd51ba5246
- PerformancePoint: http://www.bing.com/search?q=SharePoint+2010+Performance+Point+users&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=sharepoint+2010+performance+point+users&sc=8-35&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=78b6345b8cc04d56a8aae764e11fd8cb

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Jesus for your quick  answer,

yes I will definitely asked specific question.
 I will also go through all the the links you sent.

Yes I am an advanced developer with HTML, CSS and kind of Intermediate with JAVASCRIPT, How I am going to use them without designer and no access to the server? can I use a third party editor. Please more detail on how to go about using my HTML,CSS and javascript skills to implement the sharepoint site with no server access and no SP designer.

I am also trying to google how to use those 3 languages to develop in sharepoint 2010

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or links.